# Getting the Scrollbar/Scrollpane positions from JavaFX TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Sooo, I have been gooling and looking through Oracle docs, but could not find any hint on how to gain access to the Scrollbar/Scrollpane inside my TextArea.

As the text inside my TextArea exceeds the given bound, horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear... I would like to get the current position of the vertical scrollbar.

I hope that someone can help.

EDIT: This question referes to JavaFX, sorry for not properly pointing this out.

Comment: [These Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#getScrollTop--)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs for `TextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html), `TextArea` defines `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties which represent how much the content has been scrolled horizontally and vertically, respectively.

So you can bind to or observe those properties, as needed:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollTrackingTextArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(textArea.scrollTopProperty().asString("You are %.0f pixels from the top."));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textArea, label, null, null, null);

        textArea.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                + "Suspendisse ut odio eu est rutrum fermentum. Curabitur eu volutpat ante. "
                + "Pellentesque maximus laoreet dapibus. In vulputate vestibulum lectus, "
                + "non auctor purus suscipit at. Vivamus turpis magna, condimentum nec purus id, "
                + "iaculis ultrices nisl. Quisque eget mi vitae dolor placerat hendrerit et in nisi. "
                + "Nam eget velit sem. Suspendisse porta, tellus at ornare varius, "
                + "tellus massa tempor lacus, vel dictum nibh tortor sed turpis. "
                + "Curabitur commodo urna ac pharetra vulputate. Maecenas urna erat, "
                + "convallis in imperdiet ac, mollis nec risus. Nam eleifend aliquet "
                + "libero eu maximus. Nullam hendrerit, justo consectetur imperdiet porttitor, "
                + "libero tortor egestas neque, eget laoreet metus quam non erat. "
                + "Donec interdum dignissim dolor, et maximus arcu sodales quis. "
                + "Suspendisse commodo hendrerit odio a bibendum. Suspendisse sed dolor sed urna "
                + "congue porta at nec mauris. Suspendisse non risus a turpis aliquet suscipit. "
                + "Proin quis erat et nisl commodo venenatis. Nulla ipsum lorem, "
                + "blandit non posuere id, ultricies ac est. Pellentesque ut nunc laoreet, "
                + "finibus ligula porttitor, placerat massa. Sed quis nisl gravida metus venenatis "
                + "luctus ut quis sapien. Donec a nunc elit. Donec lobortis massa massa, "
                + "a scelerisque urna fringilla non. Donec molestie cursus nunc, "
                + "at convallis quam ultrices ut. Sed sed ornare nulla, eu dapibus purus. "
                + "Integer a tortor et odio rhoncus pretium. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam ut dapibus ligula. "
                + "Aenean auctor elementum neque, at congue lectus suscipit non. Suspendisse potenti. "
                + "Fusce vestibulum ex at nunc bibendum, in porttitor est lobortis. "
                + "Nam felis ex, vestibulum et dui nec, tristique semper enim. Maecenas libero erat, "
                + "tempor vitae nisi in, porttitor tincidunt nunc.Sed congue dui eu vulputate iaculis. "
                + "Quisque urna elit, aliquet molestie viverra ut, consectetur ut risus. "
                + "In ullamcorper nec nisl non posuere. Nullam ligula sem, malesuada a ornare in, "
                + "vestibulum eu purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, "
                + "nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut molestie elit turpis, non blandit nunc consequat id. "
                + "Morbi vitae tincidunt ex. Maecenas justo odio, dapibus non iaculis a, tincidunt ut augue. "
                + "Praesent a sollicitudin neque. Curabitur in tempus nibh. Ut nec lacinia ante, ac tincidunt quam. "
                + "Phasellus porttitor tellus mi, et iaculis enim volutpat a. Nulla eget fringilla eros. "
                + "Phasellus ultricies aliquet massa. In quam leo, luctus a dolor sit amet, "
                + "facilisis consectetur enim. Vivamus ac odio et enim ultrices mattis. "
                + "Vivamus euismod nisi et posuere porttitor. Pellentesque vehicula libero id quam ultricies facilisis. "
                + "Vivamus vitae turpis vitae ligula efficitur aliquet eget eu risus. "
                + "Proin bibendum odio a lacus vulputate interdum. Nam luctus urna eu iaculis fringilla. "
                + "Quisque commodo metus risus. Quisque faucibus facilisis ultricies. "
                + "Vestibulum quis consequat nisi. Suspendisse finibus et tellus et eleifend. "
                + "Suspendisse congue malesuada urna, in eleifend arcu aliquam id. "
                + "Curabitur accumsan mi augue, ac laoreet neque viverra sit amet. Integer luctus tempus ligula non facilisis. "
                + "Maecenas eget lobortis felis.");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a JTextArea is wrapped inside a ScrollPane (and not the other way around, as suggested by your question). So try the getParent() method of your JTextArea and check if it is an instance of JScrollPane....If yes, you can get the positions of the Scroll bars.

Comment: The question is about a JavaFX `TextArea`, not a `JTextArea`, I think.

Comment: Then please make that clear in your question and please do not downvote me for that, as it was not clear that you speak about JavaFX

Comment: It's probably useful to read the tags. Also, note, not my question.

Comment: OK, thanks, did not see the [javafx] tag, however, it is a bit strict to get a downvote for my answer.