# How can I find out the relative position of the vertical scroll bar in a Java FX TextArea?

Tags: javafx, textarea, scrollbar

Java FX, a TextArea within a ScrollPane within a BorderPane's Center area.

How can I find out the current position of the vertical scroll bar? In fact what I want to know is, if the scroll bar thumb is at the bottom of the scroll bar, or not.

Whenever I look, scrollPane.getVvalue() returns 0.0, no matter where the scrollbar thumb actually is.

Any bright idea?

Thx
keksi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Scrollbar/Scrollpane positions from my TextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768658/getting-the-scrollbar-scrollpane-positions-from-my-textarea)

Comment: Many thanx for your answer. The solution mentioned returns a value in pixel (scroll bar thumb is n pixel away from the top). I'm looking for a relative value between 0.0 and 1.0. And - what I find really weird - the TextArea seems to have an own internal scrolling system - so it seems as if I don't need to wrap it into a ScrollPane, is that right?